# How can I write java code to connect a windchill

Tags: ptc-windchill

How can I make a java program, which contains a method `main(String[] args)` and must synchronize to execute it in `windchill` (8).  This will allow me to retrieve data windchill such as life cycles for example?

Comment: Just try write a code with main method and execute from wc shell..Will work

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to do this.
Using a pure java application, calling Windchill services with RMI call.
This is really the hard way, as you have to manage the classes dependencies, and many other issues.
The easiest way is to use an HTTP Client and call Infoengine tasks, either by using pure HTTP calls, or WebServices.

Any Infoengine task can be called with an URL like this one :
http://server/Windchill/servlet/IE/tasks/MyTask.xml